# Convert an array to xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, arrays

I'm looking for the solution to convert an array to XML file in Android.
If you have sample code or just the instruction, could you provide me that?
I will appreciate so much.
Thank in advance.
Thomas Le

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code might help you:

```
 protected string ConvertToXML(Object[] args, string rootName, string elemName)
    {
        string xmlStr = "<" + rootName + ">";

        foreach (Object arg in args)
        {
            xmlStr += "<" + elemName + ">" + arg.ToString() +
                      "</" + elemName + ">";
        }

        xmlStr += "</" + rootName + ">";

        return xmlStr;
    }
```

And here is how you can call the function:

```
Object[] test = { "One", "Two", 3, "Four", 5, "six" };
Response.Write(ConvertToXML(test, "params", "param"));
```

This should be the output:

```
<params>
    <param>One</param>
    <param>Two</param>
    <param>3</param>
    <param>Four</param>
    <param>5</param>
    <param>Six</param>
</params>
```

UPDATE: to save it to sd card below code might help:

```
String filename = "filename.txt";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
FileOutputStream fos;
byte[] data = new String("data to write to file").getBytes();
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(data);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

and you have to add this line to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thank for your help, Ankit HTech.
If I want to save xmlStr into SD, do you know how to do it?
Sorry. I'm just beginner in Android field.
Thank in advance.
Thomas

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your request

Comment: Hi, Ankit HITech.
According to your code, the file is created, but the content only includes "data to write to file" . There is no NODE at all.